# case statement string with regex?

Tags: actionscript

I see Switch statement in:

```
switch() {
case 'string': ...;
}
```

but would hope if I could do this?

```
switch() {
case 'string??' ...;
}
```

where ?? is like accept 2 random characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` statement. The `switch` statement isn't designed for complicated comparison.

```
if (/^string..$/.test(theString) {
   ....
```

Comment: so will the if statement is consider a little slower since I need to process data close to realtime?

Comment: @user: No, nor the `switch` statement is faster. You should profile it (if you have a choice).

Comment: Considering you can't use regex with a switch statement, it doesn't really matter if the if/else statements are "slower": there's nothing for it to be slower than.